# How to force Chrome to scroll down on fixed body height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit

Because of Chrome/iPad bugs I have to put fixed height on html and body, but than I cannot scroll down (script works in Firefox nicely):

```js
$('span').on('click', function(e) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 1200
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
/* iPad fix, has to stay! */
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
.content {
    height: 2000px;
    background: green;
}
span {
    color: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    Some content... <span>click to scroll</span>
</div>
```

How to make it work in webkit browsers, **without changing styles**?

I tried to remove fixed height while scrolling and after the animation is done to put it back - but than page scrolls back to top!

Playground on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bpf6t8y/1/).

Comment: seems like there might be an issue with overflow: auto

Comment: yes, but I found the way, shall post it now.

Comment: You have the content longer than the body, but are trying to scroll the body...

Comment: hmm, that's true, any idea why it works in firefox though?

Comment: Really have no idea, the way I hacked css and js 10 years ago for IE, now I do for Chrome, old iPhones and iPads. Would really like there was one browser, even it was old IE6. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this overflow scrolling issue we can use [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method. What I did was simple:

```
$(elementToScrollTo)[0].scrollIntoView({block: "start", behavior: "smooth"});
```

Although `scrollIntoViewOptions` are supported only by Firefox, the method works fine in all browsers.